# Azure website loading slowly at times even though 'always on' is on

Tags: azure

I am using Azure for hosting a simple SpringBoot application with a basic 'Hello World' and logs a message @PostConstruct. I have tried setting 'always on' flag both on and off and was expecting the application to restart when 'always on' is Off. But even though the app loaded a little slowly after not accessing overnight, there was no log of application restarting.

What does it mean that the application unloads on idle for some time, if it does not restart?

Any suggestions to avoid this problem of slow loading?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify which performance/pricing tier you're observing this at?

Comment: Hi David, I am at the standard pricing tier. Below the Basic Pricing tier 'Always On' functionality is not available by azure.